# Mean value theorem for Dirichlet series of prime support?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, norms, dirichlet-series

Let $\{a_n\}_{1\leq n\geq N}$, $a_n\in \mathbb{C}$. Let $F(s) = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n n^{-s}$. By a mean-value theorem (Montgomery-Vaughan, 1973),
$$\int_0^T |F(i t)|^2 = \sum_{n=1}^N |a_n|^2 (T + O(n)).$$

Now, suppose that $\{a_n\}$ has prime support (i.e., $a_n=0$ for all composite $n$). Can we obtain a better bound? (Can we save a factor of roughly $\log n$ on the term $O(n)$, say?)

(The motivation here is an (imperfect) analogy with the large sieve for sequences with prime support.)

---

An interesting case would be given by $a_p = (\log p)^2/p$ with $a_n=0$ for $n$ composite. Then $\sum_{n=1}^N |a_n|^2 n$ is in the order of $(\log N)^4$. Can we go down to $O((\log N)^3)$?

Comment: Lemma 1 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03755.pdf might be what you want.

Comment: Ah, nice! Has any work been done on improving the constant? (I suppose one can use a nicely optimized function in the style of Selberg, Vaaler, etc.?)

Comment: (Things get a bit messy in the range $T\leq n\leq T^{1+\epsilon}$, but, in my application, that may not matter much.)

Comment: (Beurling-Selberg seems to work nicely. Incidentally, what is the story of Beurling-Selberg? Who came up with the function? I take Selberg first applied it to the large sieve?)

Comment: @HAHelfgott For (at least part of) the story of B-S, see Vaaler’s very nice Bulletin of the AMS paper on extremal Fourier analysis.  Also, shouldn’t you expect to save log N instead of N?

Comment: Yes, typo! Thanks!