# For $\Phi$ a majorant of $1_{[-1/2,1/2]}$, how small can the total variation of $\widehat\Phi$ be?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, analytic-number-theory, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $\Phi:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a real-valued, symmetric, non-negative function such that $\Phi(t)\geq 1$ for $|t|\leq 1/2$. Assume furthermore that $\Phi$ and $\widehat\Phi$ are both in $L^1\cap L^2$ and finally recall that the *total variation* of a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}
\Var(f)=\sup_{n\in\Bbb N} \sup_{x_0<x_1<\dotsc<x_n} \sum_{i=1}^n |f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|.$$

1. How small can the total variation $|\widehat\Phi|_{\textrm{TV}}$ be?

   1b. Same question, under the assumption that $\Phi(0)=1$.
2. Same question, under the assumption that $C_{\Phi}:=\int_{\Bbb{R}} \max(\widehat\Phi(x),0)\; dx$ is $\leq 1 + \varepsilon$.

   2b. Under the same assumption ($C_{\Phi}\leq 1 + \epsilon$): how small can $\widehat{\Phi}(0)$ be?

---

The motivation for this question is the same as for my previous question [An optimization problem: $\Phi(0)$, $\widehat{\Phi}(0)$, $\Phi$ a majorant](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432033/an-optimization-problem-phi0-widehat-phi0-phi-a-majorant) : namely, helping to give an answer to [Mean value theorem for Dirichlet series - optimize?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417118/mean-value-theorem-for-dirichlet-series-optimize) and [Mean value theorem for Dirichlet series of prime support?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431751/mean-value-theorem-for-dirichlet-series-of-prime-support?noredirect=1#comment1111524_431751) . An argument based on the Poisson's summation formula (as in one of Noam Elkies's answers to [An optimization problem: $\Phi(0)$, $\widehat{\Phi}(0)$, $\Phi$ a majorant](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432033/an-optimization-problem-phi0-widehat-phi0-phi-a-majorant/432107?noredirect=1#comment1112413_432107)) suffices to give $|\widehat{\Phi}|_{\textrm{TV}}\geq 4$, even in case 1, i.e., without assumptions on $\Phi(0)$ or $C_{\Phi}$.

Comment: What is your definition of the Fourier transform (i.e., where do you place $2\pi$)?

Comment: $\widehat(f)(t) = \int f(x) e(-x t) dx$, where $e(y) = e^{2\pi i y}$.

Comment: I meant $\widehat{f}$, not $\hat{(f)}(t)$, obviously. Odd that it came out that way.